# Function to calculate CRC-8 value in C ++

Tags: c++, crc

I am trying to do a function to calculate the CRC-8 value but I do not get the desired result.

The chain is: 123456789

And the result should be: 0xF4

I tried this function but I could not make it work:

```
unsigned char CRC8(const unsigned char *data, unsigned char len) 
{
    unsigned char crc = 0x00;

    while (len--) 
    {
        unsigned char extract = *data++;

        for (unsigned char tempI = 8; tempI; tempI--) 
        {
            unsigned char sum = (crc ^ extract) & 0x01;
            crc >>= 1;

            if (sum) 
            {
                crc ^= 0x8C;
            }

            extract >>= 1;
        }
    }

  return crc;
}
```

Comment: Pencil and paper: write down the intermediate results. Then debug your program and compare.

Comment: Could you point out the source of the above formula?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is not your code but that your code is copied from the net and simply doesn´t match the parameters of your test data.

crc8 (as well as all the other crcXX thingies) are heavily overloaded.

You have to find or code a function that fits the paramters of your test data.

- the polynomial
- reflected or not
- crc start
- exit xor

Here´s a [catalogue](http://reveng.sourceforge.net/crc-catalogue/1-15.htm#crc.cat.crc-8-dvb-s2) wich includes some of the common CRC8´s.

Example implementations that can fit different parameters include [boost](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_37_0/libs/crc/crc.html) or this [example](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/19059/C-CCITT-CRC-Algorithm) at codeproject (its c# but moving it to c++ will be as trivial as trivial gets).

Answer (score 0):

Code should be ok, but be careful if you test it with "int" or "uint32_t" .... The bytes are stored in the reverse order in the memory, so it won't give the same result.